# can not set cakephp AuthComponent sessionKey

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.4

i am developing with cakephp 2.4.7 where i am using the auth component for multiple login (a user and a company login).

My goal is to set the right `sessionKey` (Auth.User or Auth.Company) in the `beforeFilter`. `Auth.User` is the default value in cakephp.

AppController:

```
public $helpers = array('Cache','Html','Session','Form');

public $components = array(
    'Security',
    'Cookie',
    'RequestHandler',
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'authError' => 'You must be loggedin to view this page.',
        'loginError' => 'Invalid user credentials.',
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);

public function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Auth->deny('*'); 
}
```

CompaniesController:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Company';
    //$this->Auth->sessionKey = 'Auth.Company';
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Form' => array(
            'userModel' => 'Company', // set the new userModel
            'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
        )
    );
    $this->Auth->allow('register', 'login', 'logout');
}
```

The login works perfectly, but the auth-session is still `Auth.User`. (Tested with `debug($this->Auth->User());`)

What i am doing wrong? How can i set the `AuthComponent::$sessionKey` correctly?

Comment: Are you sure `$this->Auth->user()` isn't reading from the `Company` key in session? What happens if you try to debug the whole of `$this->Session->read()` or just `$this->Session->read('Company)`? Apologies if that's a stupid question, but thought you might as try it out.

Comment: `$this->Auth->user()` returns the array set under the specified session key. So you really can't check the out of that method to know under what session key the info is stored. Does your Company model has belongsTo or hasOne association with User model?

Comment: No, company has no association to the User model.

Comment: `debug(CakeSession::read('Auth'));` returns the company array.

Comment: @q0re are you using two different tables to authenticate the user or only one table? and if so, how do you redirect them to the there respective dashboards after successful login? please help as I am new to cakephp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a same problem today, I have jumped into code [(here)](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-AuthComponent.html#$sessionKey) to check why its not working for me.

It seems that you have to set it like this

```
public function beforeFilter()
{

    AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Company'; // static property so we have to 
    // access in static way so you want get strict errors
    ...
}
```

and then logout and login user again. In your action just **var_dump()** or **pr()** the **$this->Session->read('Auth')**

Btw $this->Auth->user() will always return you array that is in the Auth by [$sessionKey] and its same for AuthComponent::user() static call.

Comment: For cakephp 3.0 we can use
`public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
  $this->Auth->sessionKey ='Auth.Company;
}`
in AppController.php to set different sessionKey for frontend and backend.

Comment: That sounds nice but this question was about cakephp 2.4.7.

Comment: Oh! I just added for someone in need for cake 3 version. Should I remove my comment if not relevant?

Comment: Up to you but I think you can leave it, maybe it will be useful for someone.